# Relation between root subgroups and the root system in unitary groups

Tags: finite-groups, algebraic-groups, root-systems

Consider a 4-dimensional non-degenerate unitary space over a field of order 4. It can be shown that there are 45 isotropic lines. For each such a line one can associate a unitary transvection and each of these transvections generates a subgroup of order two called a root subgroup. What is the relation between these root subgroups and the root system of the unitary group? In Lie notation the system is $^2\!A_3$. How  can the number 45 be explained in terms of roots?

Comment: In this case $45$ is the number of points on a flag variety of the unitary group, which can be expressed as a polynomial in $q=2$ with coefficients determined by the combinatorics of the root system. Is that the kind of thing you want to see? The different roots you describe are related to the root system indirectly, since they all stabilize different maximal tori.

Comment: I'm wondering if it is possible to somehow mark these subgroups with roots, for example, in the case of $SL_n(q)$, a root subgroup of transvections $T_{ij}(\alpha)$ corresponds to root $e_i-e_j$ of root system $A_{n-1}$.